# Cannot save object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I've been trying to save the object with localStorage, but it's not working. I'm new to Angular2.

this is my app.component code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    text = [];
    title = 'app works!';
    passText(i) {
        console.log(i);
        localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(i));
    }
}
```

this is my component.html code

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="" [(ngModel)]="text.text">
    <input type="text" name="" [(ngModel)]="text.newData">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="passText(text)">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than 'it's not working'. What is happening, and what should be happening?

Comment: Do the `console.log(i);` show the a result ?

Comment: it is saving an empty object inside localstorage

Comment: Try changing `text = []` to `text = {}` if you want an object

Comment: Core972, yes it is showing a result  as  [text: "mb nmb", newData: "nmdms"]

Comment: When you `JSON.stringify` that, the values are lost (as `Stringify` only looks at enumerable properties). You need to set those properties against an object, and either store the object, or push that object into an array and then store the array, but you can't simply add those properties onto array

Comment: Hi @kshitiz i have post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example,

Html File,

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" [(ngModel)]="text.text">
  <input type="text" name="" [(ngModel)]="text.newData">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="passText(text)">submit</button>
</div>
Output
{{model | json}}
```

Typescript File,

```
 model:any[]=[]; // for display output 
 text:any = {};  //changed variable array to object type.
  passText(i) {
      console.log("Data",i);
      localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(i));
  }
  getText(){
      this.model=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('text'));
  }
```

Output screenshots,

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this solution

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    text:any ={
        text:'',
        newData:''
    } ;
    title = 'app works!';
    passText(i) {
        console.log(i);
        localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(i));
    }
    getData() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('text')));
    }
}



<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text.text">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text.newData">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="passText(text)">submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getData()">Get Data from Local storag</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic way of handling this you dont even need setItem and you don't need serialise using stringify even since, localStorage can serialise itself. please find the updated snipet.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    text = [];
    title = 'app works!';
    passText(i) {
        console.log(i);
        localStorage['text'] = i;
    }
}
```

Note:- You cannot serialise event in JavaScript. If you do so some of the implementation properties like event.target will be missing.

Comment: I am using this technique, it just makes an empty text at localstorage. Can you update any working fiddle or plunker

Comment: @kshitiz can you attach the log of `console.log(i);` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(i));` in passText method